# retrieve part of Linux directory path

Tags: java, linux, path, environment-variables

I am getting value of Linux environment variable in JAVA code as follows:

```
String path = getEnv("MY_HOME")

//MY_HOME corresponds to mydir/myproject/proj/landing_page/home
```

I want to write a method that returns absolute directory path- mydir/myproject/logs using MY_HOME environment variable.

Can anyone please suggest how I can retrieve 'mydir/myproject/'part of the path in MY_HOME?

Comment: Why don't you just split the `path` value and reconstruct it with the subpaths you need?

Comment: It doesn't work to ask questions like "I have a string `mydir/myproject/proj/landing_page/home` and I want to get `mydir/myproject`".  This doesn't help us, because we don't know what you want with _other_ strings besides `mydir/myproject/proj/landing_page/home`.  What exactly do you want?  The first two components of the path?  Everything up to the first "t"?  Or something else?  The first step is to figure out what you require and how to state it precisely.

Comment: I cannot do that because the path of mydir will be different for different users. So, I need something like- retrieve MY_HOME, go 3 levels up (to get mydir/myproject), and then append the new directory to the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you are looking for `File`'s `getParentFile` method:

```
new File(getEnv("MY_HOME")).getParentFile().getAbsolutePath()
```

Answer (score 1):

Path class in java IO has subpath method
so you can do the following:

```
Path path = Paths.get("one/two/three");
System.out.println(path.subpath(0, 2));
```

the output will be "one/two";

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use [`System.getEnv(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28java.lang.String%29) method.

If you want parts of `MY_HOME` by going 3 levels up then you can probably do:

```
String logPath = myHome + "/../../../logs";
```

OR to get first 2 parts of path:

```
String arr[] = myHome.split("/");
String logPath="";
if (arr.length > 2)
    logPath = arr[0] + '/' + arr[1] + "/logs";
System.out.println(logPath); // mydir/myproject/logs
```

Comment: I am using getEnv method to retrieve MY_HOME. But I need to use selected part of  retrieved MY_HOME to set another environment variable

Comment: Thanks anubhava for your method.